# Nested IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, nested-if

The following is something I have tried after some research on nested IF's however it only gives expected results for the first part of the statement and not the remainder, can anyone explain why or do I need a different type of function?

```
=if(h4="basic","basic",if(g17>=500,"Standard",if(h4="standard","Standard",if(g17>=750,"Standard+",if(g17<=500,"Basic",if(h4="Standard+","standard+",If(g17<=750,"Standard",if(g17>=850,"Platinum",if(h4="Platinum","Platinum",if(g17<=850,"Standard+","Platinum"))))))))))
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: One thing you may want to try is the built in "Evaluate Formula" under "Formula Auditing" (at least that's where it is in Excel 2007).  That will allow you to step through each if statement and see where it stops and allow you to see why it's not doing what you're expecting.

Comment: Two questions for you. `1` Which Excel version are you using? `2` You have tagged the question as `Excel-VBA`. Are you looking for a formula or code?

Comment: You Should First start by clearly stating what you want the code to do, I bet you will figure it out on your on. Just say If H4 is any of these values, then use those values, other wise if G17's value is greater then x then y and so on, use this method and you should be able to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the advice I do not think I explained myself too well, but in the end with some of the suggestions was able to work it out here is the finished formula:

```
=IF(AND(H4="Basic",G17<450),"Basic",IF(AND(H4="Basic",G17>=450),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17<450),"Basic",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17>449,G17<700),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17>=700),"Standard+",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17>699,G17<800),"Standard+",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17<700),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17>=800),"Platinum",IF(AND(H4="Platinum",G17<800),"Standard+","Platinum")))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one if

```
if(g17>=500
```

and later on you have

```
if(g17>=750
```

The last condition will never be "satisfied", for if it is actually true, it will not be tested for, as the first `if(g17>=500` will be `True`.

I do not know what are the "expected results", "the first part of the statement", or "the remainder", but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was expecting it to search through the Ifs and find the condition that was matched, when I test it the first result comes up ok but when I change to match a subsequent if statement the expected result "Standard+" or "Platinum" etc does not show, the first part is the first if condition and the remainder is the other 9 thanks

Comment: Ok how can I write it as: greater than 500 but less than 750 in the statement as the logical test it

Comment: I am still not sure what do you expect. Just in case, try `=IF(H4="basic","basic",IF(AND(G17>=500,G17<750),"Standard",IF(H4="standard","Standard",IF(G17>=750,"Standard+",IF(G17<=500,"Basic",IF(H4="Standard+","standard+",IF(G17<=750,"Standard",IF(G17>=850,"Platinum",IF(H4="Platinum","Platinum",IF(G17<=850,"Standard+","Platinum"))))))))))`, or add `AND` operators in subsequent tests as needed.

Comment: If [Applying multiple conditions to formula](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912816/applying-multiple-conditions-to-formula) aims at the same objective as this one, please edit your question instead of posting a new one, to keep with the thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
=IFERROR( INDEX({"basic","Standard","Standard+","Platinum"},MATCH(H4,{"basic","Standard","Standard+","Platinum"},0)),IF(G17>850,"Platinum",IF(G17>750,"Standard+",IF(G17>500,"Standard","Basic"))))
```