# Applying multiple conditions to formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, multiple-conditions, vba

I have a situation where I need to apply several "value boundaries" to several different "starting positions" and then subsequently output the "ongoing position".

The "value boundaries" are: <500, >=500<750, >750<=850 and >850

The  "starting positions" are "Basic", "Standard", "Standard+", and "Platinum",

The value boundaries are then applied and the "ongoing position" outputted,

e.g. a person starting at "Basic" achieves 600 and then moves to "standard", or someone at "Platinum" gets 700 so reverts to "Standard+" etc etc, I have tried this with a nested IF to no avail .

Edit: it seems the solution is beyond a formula do I need VBA to solve this one?

Comment: isn't this the same as your last question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested IF statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911872/nested-if-statement)

Comment: Yes I reworded to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled to get an answer to this but eventually with the help of the suggestions I was able to work it out, here is the finished formula:

```
=IF(AND(H4="Basic",G17<450),"Basic",IF(AND(H4="Basic",G17>=450),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17<450),"Basic",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17>449,G17<700),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard",G17>=700),"Standard+",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17>699,G17<800),"Standard+",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17<700),"Standard",IF(AND(H4="Standard+",G17>=800),"Platinum",IF(AND(H4="Platinum",G17<800),"Standard+","Platinum")))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is ok for you to have a table with the ranges somewhere, this will work for you.

Cell F1 contains the formula (as text) that is used in E1. Then you can copy-paste downwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without a VLOOKUP() table:

=IF(A1<500,"Basic",IF(AND(A1>=500,A1<750),"Standard",IF(AND(A1>=750,A1<800),"Standard+","Platinum")))

**NOTE:**

In VBA, the **And** syntax is slightly different.

Comment: Thanks for that, i forgot to say that the system is a one step at a time change only, therefore the depending on the starting position the above boundaries only result in one step up or down, e.g. someone at Platinum who gains 400 will then go to "Standard+" and not "Basic" how can I get this functionality into the formula

Comment: the above works on a single condition, but as I say above I need to be able to apply a one step move to differing starting positions, any thoughts?

Comment: I can solve this, but it will require a "helper" column.  Are you O.K. with this??

Comment: Yes but not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you will input two numbers and, based on where these numbers fall with regard to your boundary conditions, the ongoing position will be determined.  Furthermore, the ongoing position cannot be more than "one different" from the starting position.

That being the case, and with the First Score in D1, and the Second Score in E1, the following formula will, I think, output the ongoing position:

> =CHOOSE(MATCH(D1,{0;500;750;850})+SIGN(
>   MATCH(E1,{0;500;750;850})-MATCH(
>   D1,{0;500;750;850})),"Basic","Standard","Standard+","Platinum")

Comment: The score accumulates over 14 days and is then set against my boundary conditions moving up or down one step or staying the same depending on the boundary, and the points total obtained. the ongoing condition is then outputted for the next 14 day period until reassessment, hope that makes sense, I will try your example and tinker if I can

Comment: Now you are now including yet another parameter that you did not provide in your initial post.  If you cannot adapt one of the provided solutions to your problem, you will need to sit back and think about how you can fully explain your problem. Where is the data input?  How do we know when 14 days have passed?  In other words, how have you set up your worksheet?  And how do you want the results displayed.  Then re-read your post and ensure you have provided everything needed with clarity; and also information as to what you have tried; what results you obtained; and what results you expected.

Answer (score 0):

O.K....Put the sequence of values in column A.  In B1 enter:

=IF(A1<500,0,IF(AND(A1>=500,A1<750),1,IF(AND(A1>=750,A1<800),2,3)))  and copy down

this will generate a code 0 thru 3 to represent the four levels

In C1 enter:

=B1

In C2 enter:

=IF(ABS(B1-B2)<2,B2,IF(B2>B1,B1+1,B1-1))   and copy down

column C implements the one-step limit.  Finally in D1 enter:

=CHOOSE(C1+1,"Basic","Standard","Standard+","Platinum")  and copy down

This converts the codes to word-levels

[image]

Comment: trying to get my head round this not sure i have explained it fully the person starts on a given level Basic Standard etc then accumulates points over 14 days, then depending on their start point they move up down or stay the same as a result of the points total e.g a person starting on Standard needs >=750 to move up to standard+ 500-749 to stay the same or <500 to move down to basic. e.g2 A Standard+ person needs >=850 to move up to platinum, 750-849 to stay at Standard+, and if <750 will go down to Standard, the points accumulate daily to a total assessed against this criteria every 14 days